# draw layout with skewed corners in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, layout

I need to draw skewed corners in my layout , basically my layout height is 60dp , i have tried to do them using an xml file of layer-list , but it is not giving the desired specially when devices gets larger in screen , i would like to get some help or if possible to draw these skewed corners programmatically so they fix into all screens and when also screen is rotated , Thank you

- This is my xml file

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/bgColor" />
    
    <item android:top="-20dp"
        android:bottom="-50dp"
        android:left="-20dp"
        android:right="400dp">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="368"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="00%">
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#DFDBDB"/>
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
    <item android:top="-20dp"
        android:bottom="-50dp"
        android:left="395dp"
        android:right="-120dp">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="-371"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="00%">
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid
                    android:color="?android:colorBackground"/>
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

- Desired Result

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

calculating the coordinates of points to join Path() is the most important thing in your work. my calculation is based on the width of the View.
Hope it can help you.

```
class SkewedCornerView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : View(context, ttrs) {

    private val path = Path()
    val paint = Paint().apply {
        flags = Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG
        color = Color.WHITE
        style = Paint.Style.STROKE
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
//        super.onDraw(canvas)
        val padding = height/50f
        paint.strokeWidth = padding
        canvas?.drawColor(Color.BLACK)
        canvas?.apply {
            path.reset()
            val cornerSize = width / 15f
            val width = width.toFloat()
            val height = height.toFloat()
//            path.moveTo(padding, height-padding)
            path.moveTo(padding, height/2)
            path.lineTo(cornerSize, padding)
            path.lineTo(width - cornerSize-padding, padding)
            path.lineTo(width-padding, height/2)
//            path.lineTo(width-padding, height-padding)
//            path.lineTo(padding, height-padding)
//            path.close()
            drawPath(path, paint)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you mate , i appreciate it , it did actually work , one thing is that those cut corners , can i set their color to transparent , i mainly need only area within white stroke to be black , but those corners outside the white stroke should be transaparent , can i set this within the custom class ?

Comment: Yes, you can. You can change `paint.style`  to Fill, dont forget to remove `canvas?.drawColor(Color.BLACK)` and change the `paint.color`.

Answer (score 1):

To draw skewed corners programmatically, you can create a custom view that extends View or one of its subclasses, such as RelativeLayout or FrameLayout. In the onDraw method of your custom view, you can use a Path object to define the shape of your view and then fill it with a color or a drawable.

Here's an example of how you can create a custom view with skewed corners

```
class SkewedCornerView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : View(context, attrs) {

private val path = Path()

override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
    super.onDraw(canvas)
    canvas?.apply {
        path.reset()
        val cornerSize = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.corner_size).toFloat()
        val width = width.toFloat()
        val height = height.toFloat()
        path.moveTo(0f, 0f)
        path.lineTo(0f, height - cornerSize)
        path.lineTo(cornerSize, height)
        path.lineTo(width, height)
        path.lineTo(width, 0f)
        path.close()
        val paint = Paint().apply {
            color = Color.WHITE
            style = Paint.Style.FILL
        }
        drawPath(path, paint)
    }
}
}
```

In this example, the path object is used to define the shape of the view. The cornerSize variable is used to specify the size of the skewed corner, which can be defined in your resources as a dimension value. The onDraw method is called every time the view needs to be redrawn, such as when the screen is rotated or the view's dimensions change.

You can add this custom view to your layout using XML or programmatically. Here's an example of how you can add it to a ConstraintLayout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="60dp">
<com.example.app.SkewedCornerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/bgColor"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

In this example, the SkewedCornerView is added as a child of a ConstraintLayout and fills its parent's dimensions. The background attribute is used to specify the background color of the view, which in this case is bgColor.

Comment: Hey mate , I appreciate your time and help , i have added as you said but for some reason the bg color remains why even though i'm setting black bg , any reason why , this is a screenshot from my code https://ibb.co/C6CP2gf